# Why is Present Perfect used if we talk about youth?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> He seems to know French very well: he is said to *have spent* his youth in Paris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He seems to know French very well: he **is said** to have spent his youth in Paris

Present perfect is used in this sentence not because it's about youth, but because it's [reported speech](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/reported-speech-1-statements) (somebody told you that he had spent his youth in Paris), so the tense is backshifted.

If you remove **is said**, it is no longer reported speech, so you don't need to backshift:

> He seems to know French very well: he spent his youth in Paris

Comment: Or if you change the syntactic role of **is said** - *He seems to know French very well: **it is said that** he spent his youth in Paris*.

Comment: But what direct speech is here, if Present Perfect is used?

Comment: @MasonGabe Direct speech: Somebody said "he spent his youth in Paris". Indirect speech: He is said to have spent his youth in Paris.

Comment: @JavaLatte But shouldn't we use Past Perfect instead of Present Perfect? When we backshift, Past Simple changes to Past Perfect, right?

Comment: @MasonGabe that would normally be true, but you can't say **to had spent**. This web page explains about the various forms of **is said**.  https://www.grammarbank.com/it-is-said-that.html